# Masked operations on GPU using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I devised a simple program to explore solutions to a problem. Observing that it  was very regular I expected to be able to easily take advantage of the GPU. But the performance was quite bad, so I came up with this minimal reproducible example.

```py
import torch
def find_pairs(fn, y, n1, n2):
    while torch.any(n2 > n1):
        s = torch.sign(fn(n1) + fn(n2) - y)
        yield s == 0, n1, n2
        n1[s == -1] += 1
        n2[(s != -1) & (n2 > n1)] -= 1;
```

Where `fn` represents any increasing function, `n1 < n2` are integer numbers, it will yield solutions to `fn(n1) + fn(n2) == y`.

A simple example is to find Pythagorean triples

```py
n = torch.arange(1, 2**13, dtype=torch.int64, device='cuda')
n1 = torch.ones_like(n)
n2 = torch.clone(n)
d = 0
for m, n1, n2 in find_pairs(lambda x: x**2, n**2, n1, n):
    d += m & (n2 > n1)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
```

That takes around `8 seconds`, if I run it on CPU it takes around `3.5 seconds`.

Can anyone tell why it so slow, is there a way to make it to take full advantage of the GPU computation potential?

Comment: WIth 2^13 values my GPU (Tesla T4) is not fully utilized. In my benchmarks, the GPU is ~4x faster (vs old 2018 Xeon CPU) starting from 2^15 values. Boolean index gathering like `n1[s == -1] += 1` is generally slow. Adding/subtracting the mask directly with `n1.add_(s == -1); n2.sub_(((s != -1) & (n2 > n1)).view(torch.uint8))` is more efficient (about ~2x).